# postback (a la ASP.NET) in other frameworks?

Tags: postback

I am researching web frameworks that are in common usage.  In ASP.NET there is the notion of a "postback".  Specifically, the framework automatically adds a hidden FORM to each page which can be submitted by JavaScript with various state parameters, etc.  The "action" URL for this form is always the current page's URL, including its query-string parameters.

I am trying to find other frameworks that have this behavior, i.e. that automatically alter the page's HTML and add forms (or links) to the current page in some form.

If anyone can point me to frameworks that do this, preferably with a reference to a doc or an example, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Application Express, http://apex.oracle.com/

Generates a FORM element that contains all items on the page, and handles state for these items when the form is submitted.